# Why does Python discriminate positive and negative values of zero,?

Tags: python, zero

I ran the following program on Python IDLE

```py
while x<1000:
    print(x**x)
    x=x-1
```

And received the following output: 
Alternating positive and negative numbers for a while (like long float numbers with alternating signs)
Then came this part, which was puzzling.

```
-0.0
0.0
-0.0
0.0
-0.0
0.0
```

Why does Python show it as negative and positive zero?
Isn't that just plain wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the bad text formatting. I'm new here!

Comment: In short, it is to comply with IEEE 754.

Comment: see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero and: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 . what is your starting value of `x` before the loop?

Comment: i started with x=1

Comment: what exactly is IEE 754?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: That's interesting(I mean IEEE 754), but it doesn't really have much of a purpose, does it?